# Why is my program crashing when I'm trying to fill up an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, crash

So with this program, basically, I ask for the names of three people, and store those strings in an array. That parts seems to work fine.

After that, I ask for their quarterly reports. So each person gets 4, and it's ordered through the array so that:

Index 0-3 goes to person A

Index 4-7 goes to person B

And index 8-11 goes to person C.

In this second for-loop that processes this second array, I have a list of if/else if statements that determine the name of the person in question that I will be asking for. In the separate function itself, readSales(), I have a similar thing set up to determine which quarter to ask for. This is designed to loop 12 times in order to get all 12 indexes filled.

For some reason, after I input the people's names, the program crashes. Any idea why?

Also, I know "using namespace std;" isn't very popular, but that's how my professor wants it so that's how I have it.

```
// In this program, I will
// (1) Ask for the names of three salespeople.
// (2) Accept sales for each quarter (for each person).
// (3) Display their name and total sales amount.

// I will use three functions:
// (1) main
// (2) readInfo 
// (3) displayInfo

// No global variables, and I will pass data as parameters.

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

// In order to pass an array through a void function,
// I must create it in the main function.

// So...

string readNames(int); // Function that gathers data from user.
double readSales(string, int);
void displayInfo(); // Function that displays final result.

int main() // Our main function
{
    // Create my variables for arrays and final result.
    string arrNames[3];
    double arrSales[12], result;

    // I must call my first function now.
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        arrNames[i] = readNames(i); // Successfully gathers all 3 names and stores them in the array. Woo!
    }



    // Now I must gather the number data, using a double array.
    string person = "uninitialized";

    int x = 0;
    for (x; x < 12; x++);
    {
        if (x < 4) // setup to ask question
            person = arrNames[0];
        if (x < 8)
            person = arrNames[1];
        if (x < 12)
            person = arrNames[2];

        arrSales[x] = readSales(person, x); // Successfully gathers all 12 quarters and stores them. Yay!
    }

    cout << arrNames[3];


} // end function main()

string readNames(int count)
{
    for (count; count < 3;)
    {
        string i;

        cout << "Please input salesperson " << count + 1 << "'s name: ";
        cin >> i;
        cout << endl;

        return i;
    }

    return 0;
} // end function readNames()

double readSales(string person, int count) // reading the sales
{
    double i; // variable I am returning at the end of function.
    int quarter;

    if (count == 0 || count == 4 || count == 8)
    {
        quarter = 1;
    }

    else if (count == 1 || count == 5 || count == 9)
    {
        quarter = 2;
    }

    else if (count == 2 || count == 6 || count == 10)
    {
        quarter = 3;
    }

    else if (count == 3 || count == 7 || count == 11)
    {
        quarter = 4;
    }
    else
        return 0;

    cout << "Please input salesperson " << person << "'s sales for Quarter " << quarter << " (Please round to the nearest cent): $" << endl;
    cin >> i;

    return i;
}
```

Comment: Knowing what the crash is is important.  But I suspect it is because the program is trying to read input from cin (which is a string) and store it into a double (which it can't do implicitly).

Comment: `std::cout << arrName[3]` leads to undefined behaviour (`arrNames` has only 3 elements, not 4).

Comment: Wait, why does ´return 0` even compile, when you have to return a `std::string`?

Comment: Without the return 0, I get this error when I compile it "not all control paths return a value" @zeta

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out @drescherjm I didn't catch that :D

Comment: `cout << arrNames[3];` besides the UB will not print the array.

Comment: @Zeta - `std::string` has a constructor taking `const char*` which sort of matches the `0`, but crashes when fed a null pointer.

Comment: @BoPersson: Yeah, I remember that one, but for a second I thought it was an explicit one. Time to go offline for today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remove the semi-colon in the `for (x; x < 12; x++);`

You can make it like this,

```
int x = 0;
for (x; x < 12; x++)
{
    if ((x >= 0) && ( x <= 3)) // setup to ask question
    {
        person = arrNames[0];
    }
    else if ((x >= 4) && (x <= 7))
    {
        person = arrNames[1];
    }
    else
    {
         person = arrNames[2];
    }


    arrSales[x] = readSales(person, x); // Successfully gathers all 12 quarters and stores them. Yay!
}
```